# What are the differences between Google Chrome extensions and Firefox add-ons?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have been developing Chrome extensions and as I have already mentioned in a question on SO, I have problems paying that starting charge witch Google asks. So I quit wasting my time developing extensions for a company that has no respect for developers and I'm starting to develop Firefox add-ons. So I'm a total newbie in this area.

First of all I have to mention that I am NOT looking for an automatic functionality/way to convert them. I have noticed that one difference between Firefox add-ons and Chrome extensions is that there is not such a thing as *popup.html* in Firefox (maybe I'm wrong).

How can I find other main differences so that I can convert my extensions to Firefox add-on?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox addons do have a popup paneil in their SDK available to use(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html).

I'm developing a Firefox addon right now and I can tell you that their actual SDK and the develop environments are great, cfx to work offline or the online builder, both are powerful and easy.

Regarding the differences that you ask, besides a few structure differences and of course Chrome or Firefox specific code that is not going to work in the other platform, I think that it should be easy port an addon from one platform to another, no automatic but pretty straightforward.